# Unity MeshRenderer.materials array index out of range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I've never used submeshes before, but I nearly have them working. I'm getting an 'array index out of range' error on the second attempt to set the mainTexture of the meshRenderer materials. I'm setting the subMeshCount to 2, and trying to apply 2 materials at index 0 and index 1. I'm having trouble understanding how index 1 can be out of bounds. Is there perhaps some line of code to tell the renderer how many materials to expect? Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Was misinterpreting the error log slightly.

```
 void Update () {

    List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
    List<int> dirtTriangles = new List<int>();
    List<int> grassTriangles = new List<int>();
    List<Vector2> uvList = new List<Vector2>();
    mesh.Clear ();

    //draw faces
    addFace(mesh,uvList,vertices,dirtTriangles,DIR.front);
    addFace (mesh,uvList,vertices,dirtTriangles,DIR.back);
    addFace (mesh,uvList,vertices,dirtTriangles,DIR.left);
    addFace (mesh,uvList,vertices,dirtTriangles,DIR.right);
    addFace (mesh,uvList,vertices,grassTriangles,DIR.top);
    addFace (mesh,uvList,vertices,dirtTriangles,DIR.bottom);

    mesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray ();
    //mesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray();

    mesh.subMeshCount = 2;
    mesh.SetTriangles (dirtTriangles.ToArray(),0);
    mesh.SetTriangles (grassTriangles.ToArray(),1);
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    mesh.uv = uvList.ToArray();

    //set materials
    meshRenderer.materials[0].mainTexture = Resources.Load("block_speckled") as Texture;
    meshRenderer.materials[1].mainTexture = Resources.Load("block_grass") as Texture; //error

    var shader = Shader.Find ("Particles/Alpha Blended");
    meshRenderer.materials[0].shader = shader; //not sure if this is correct either
    meshRenderer.materials[1].shader = shader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
meshRenderer.materials = new[] 
{
    new Material(Shader.Find("Your/Shader")), 
    new Material(Shader.Find("Your/Shader"))
}

meshRenderer.materials[0].mainTexture = Resources.Load("AssetName") as Texture;
meshRenderer.materials[1].mainTexture = Resources.Load("AssetName") as Texture;
```

Comment: Isn't that just a slight refactor of essentially identical code? What is the key difference?

Comment: Key difference is you have to add materials to array before access them.

meshRenderer.materials[0].mainTexture = ...
is working because you have one element array by default.